# Can taking escitalopram produce a false-positive result in a urinary metanephrine/normetanephrine test?

Tags: antidepressants, ssri-selective-serotonin

I'm wondering whether taking escitalopram (5 mg/day) might spoil the results of a 24-hour urinary metanephrine/normetanephrine analysis.

I googled and found this mention of escitalopram in *[Pheochromocytoma: pitfalls
in the biochemical evaluation](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1586/17446651.2014.887985?needAccess=true)* (Dobri et al., 2014):

> Although tricyclic antidepressants are known to increase NE/NMN levels, newer classes of antidepressants which inhibit NE neuronal reuptake are potentially associated with falsepositive results. Clinicians need to inquire about the use of
>   serotonin NE reuptake inhibitors (venlafaxine, duloxetine), selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs: fluoxetine, sertraline, citalopram, **escitalopram**) and NE DA reuptake inhibitors (bupropion). Neary et al. reported a patient with plasma NMN > fourfolds ULN while on venlafaxine, which returned to normal 2 weeks after discontinuation of the drug [64].

However, this article cites only one case report, and that is not for escitalopram but for venlafaxine, which is not an SSRI but SNRI. Are there reports of escitalopram drastically affecting urinary metanephrine/normetanephrine levels?